# Best efficient way to write a big string of bytes to file

Tags: java, string, file, byte, arrays

I am writing a string of bits to a file like this :

```
//String to ByteArray
byte[] b = new BigInteger(encodedFile.toString(), 2).toByteArray();
//Writing
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName.concat(".file"),true);
fos.write(b);
```

It works fine for string of bits from a file of 100kb but bigger than that, it gets very slow.

Whats is the best efficient way to do it with larger strings of bits ?

Comment: tried BufferedOutputStream?

Comment: What's the type of `encodedFile`? What's "very slow"? (seconds, minutes, hours?)

Comment: Have you tested the code to see what part is slow? I would do that first and then decide what the best way to continue is. You might need to write the file out differently, or change how you convert the string to byte array, but you need to know what is slow first.

Comment: I wager its creating the BigInteger thats sucking up all your time. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Last, but not least: custom binary serialisation is almost never the right idea. (Unless you're coding against a predefined protocol.)

Comment: I know that ta code is slow in the line of BigInteger, i use the cpu clock. The encodedFile is simply a String of 1's and 0's .

Comment: What's the point? All you're doing here is reconstructing the original bytes, at an immense cost. Why not just write the *original* bytes and get rid of the encoding step altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to write String to file using java nio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366266/best-way-to-write-string-to-file-using-java-nio)

Answer (score 0):

In general, interpreting a string of characters in a positional number system is quite expensive. The BigInteger constructor is not optimized for the special case where the radix is a power of two. This is evident with a little testing:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    char[] digits = new char[200000];
    Arrays.fill(digits, '1');
    String s = new String(digits);

    StopWatch watch = new StopWatch("new BigInteger");
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(s, 2);
    watch.done();
    watch = new StopWatch("toByteArray");
    byte[] data = bigInt.toByteArray();
    watch.done();
}
```

For 200k digits, this prints:

> ```
> new BigInteger took 0.772188085
> toByteArray took 0.001747708
> ```

For 100k digits, this prints:

> ```
> new BigInteger took 0.200759594
> toByteArray took 0.000973587
> ```

Obviously, new BigInteger employs an O(n^2) algorithm.

Knowing that we convert a binary number, we can simplify the conversion:

```
static byte[] convert(String binaryString) {
    // assumes binaryString.length() is a multiple of 8
    byte[] bytes = new byte[binaryString.length() / 8];
    byte data = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        int minIndex = i * 8;
        int maxIndex = (i + 1) * 8;
        for (int j = minIndex; j < maxIndex; j++) {
            data <<= 1;
            data |= binaryString.charAt(j) - '0';
        }
        bytes[i] = data;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Running this on a char array with 1 million characters, we get:

> ```
> new BigInteger took 19.086559046
> toByteArray took 0.003656331
> convert took 0.009119036
> ```

The above code is untested, use at your own risk :-)

For really large numbers, it might be worthwhile to write the bytes to the OutputStream as they are converted. If you do that, you should use a BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: Thank you, but note that when doing to Byte Array it writes it on the file like a string ( 10101010 ), the biginteger forces it to write real binary.

Comment: Why do you think I need to "note" that? The convert method does the same thing as the first line of the code you posted (subject to the caveats above), but 3 orders of magnitude faster ...