# Can I use the eclipse debugger to write a variable to a file

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to create some sort of "trace breakpoint" in eclipse whereby Eclipse will log variables that I choose to a file when a "breakpoint" is hit without pausing the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. For this sample method:

```
public static void logArgs(final String one, final String two) {
    System.out.println(one + two);
}
```

put your breakpoint in it, right click it and edit `Breakpoint properties...` as in the example. The important checkboxes are `Conditional` and `Suspend when 'true'`. Just return `false` so that breakpoint does not suspend at all.

```
java.io.FileWriter w = new java.io.FileWriter("/tmp/file.txt", true);
w.write(String.format("args(%s, %s)%n"), one, two));
w.close();
return false;
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. And if you write all four statements on one line, it also works in the expression view.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 11 Michał Grzejszczak's answer can be written as
`java.nio.file.Files.writeString(java.nio.file.Path.of("f.txt"), "My string to save");return true;`

([Best way to write String to file using java nio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366266/best-way-to-write-string-to-file-using-java-nio))